# Can the initial image be adjusted in the Xamarin PhotoView component?

Tags: xamarin, imageview, xamarin.android, android-photoview

I'm using the [PhotoView](https://components.xamarin.com/view/photoview) component to zoom and pan an image in Android. However, when it first goes to the page where the image is, it is positioned in the top left corner and when I try to pan or zoom it shifts to the middle. Does anyone have experience with this component and know how to adjust the initial position of the image and prevent it from jumping to the middle of the screen?

Comment: the source is here: https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView

Comment: post your code and your layout

Comment: what ScaleType are you using? https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView/issues/308

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
PhotoViewAttacher attacher;
attacher.SetScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FitCenter)
```

Some options for ScaleType:

- ImageView.ScaleType.FitCenter
- ImageView.ScaleType.FitStart
- ImageView.ScaleType.Center
- ImageView.ScaleType.CenterCrop
- ImageView.ScaleType.CenterInside